# Facebook, Reddit, Skype all sites showing 404 preview of my site

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, skype, reddit

everyone I am stuck on a issue. I tried adding **OG Metas** and disabling **Apache mod_security** but still getting 404 page preview in **Facebook, Reddit, Skype** any help will be really appreciated my website URL is http://www.gamescottage.com/ Guys I really need your help I am stuck on this issue. My site is developed in Laravel.

Comment: This is what Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamescottage.com%2F . It say: ErrorException Undefined variable: ub

Comment: Maybe an answer rather than comment, but.. perhaps they are actually adhering to your robots.txt file.. some coders/people actually do
http://www.gamescottage.com/robots.txt

Comment: @DuaneLortie I removed robots.txt but still it is showing 404

Comment: @WizKid Thanks bro that solved my problem you can post your answer I will accept that :)